# Check if multiple divs are visible at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been using the following code to check if a div is visible:

```
if ($("#monday").is(':visible')) {
    document.getElementById('scheduleitem1').style.width = 540;
    $("#scheduleitem1").show();                     
}
```

That code worked fine. However I want to check if one of multiple divs are visible at once.

I've tried the following codes which did not work:

```
if ($("#monday" || "#tuesday").is(':visible')) {
    document.getElementById('scheduleitem1').style.width = 540;
    $("#scheduleitem1").show();                     
}
```

and

```
if ($("#monday", "#tuesday").is(':visible')) {
    document.getElementById('scheduleitem1').style.width = 540;
    $("#scheduleitem1").show();                     
}
```

So how do I do if I want to check if one of multiple divs are visible at once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this :

```
$("#monday,#tuesday").is(':visible')
```

http://api.jquery.com/is/ : "... return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments".

Answer (score 2):

Check length of selected elements `$("#monday,#tuesday").find(":visible").length == 1`

Something like

```
if ($("#monday,#tuesday").find(":visible").length == 1) {
    document.getElementById('scheduleitem1').style.width = 540;
    $("#scheduleitem1").show();                     
}
```

Comment: You're not such a @StupidDev :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($("#monday").is(':visible')  || $("#tuesday").is(':visible')) {
    $("#scheduleitem1").css('width', '540px').show();                     
}
```

I would add a wrapper to all week days and do something like this:

```
if($("#weekDays").find('div:visible')) {
    $("#scheduleitem1").css('width', '540px').show();                     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware the question states that only one element must be visible.
This answer is for future visitors who want to check if all the elements are visible.

```
// Assume that the elements are visible
var is_visible = true;
// Select the elements wanted and go through each of them one by one
$("#monday, #tuesday, #etc").each(function() {
  // Check that the assumption is true for each element selected
  if (!$(this).is(':visible')) {
    is_visible = false;
  }
});
if (is_visible) {
    $("#scheduleitem1").width(540).show();                     
}
```

Update, for brevity:

```
// Check if the elements are not hidden.
if (!$("#monday, #tuesday, #etc").is(':hidden')) {
    $("#scheduleitem1").width(540).show();                     
}
```